# Why do I see cookies from sites that I have never visited?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

Using google chrome I see many cookies from sites that I have never visited. How is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are [third-party cookies](https://www.techtarget.com/whatis/definition/third-party-cookie), likely for advertisement on a website, or used to track your viewing. Most browsers, including Chrome, have [settings to block third-party cookies](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/block-allow-third-party-cookies-in-ie-chrome-firefox-opera).

That said, Chrome Browser has [delayed banning all third-party cookies until 2024](https://www.engadget.com/google-delays-phaseout-of-third-party-cookies-from-chrome-192422591.html), but will replace it with Federated Learning of Cohorts (FLoC) to track users. If privacy is a concern, [consider other browsers](https://vpnoverview.com/privacy/anonymous-browsing/best-browsers-for-privacy/).